# Autocomplete doesn't work.... (AJAX+PHP+HTML+JS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've created autocomplete function but it doesn't work. I see no error and can't find out what's wrong...

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Metamorphous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src ="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="main" class="down">
                <header>
                    <h1>HerbariuM</h1>
                </header>
                <nav>
                    <input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Szukaj..." onfocus="mainUp()" onblur="mainDown()">
                </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="herb" class="hide">
            <img id="image" src="">
            <h2><i>Losowa roślinka</i></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's just a fragment of code for autocomplete **JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#searchBar").autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response){
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{q:request.term},
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event,ui){
        alert("Selected: "+ui.item.label);
    }
});
});
```

And this is PHP code to return data from database **PHP:**

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","herbarium");

$herb = $_GET['q'];

$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM herbs WHERE latin_name LIKE '%$herb%'");

$data = array();

while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row['latin_name'];
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Could anyone advice me how to fix it? Got no idea, have searched whole internet and all lines of code one by one but see no error...

Comment: When you debug, how/where does this fail?  When you step through the code while it's executing, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the inputs to that operation?  What was the result?  What result did you expect?  Why?  (Also note that your code is wide open to SQL injection and you're not checking for database errors.)

Comment: Please add more detail on how it doesn't work: do your functions get called, is the request sent to the proper address, does the request get processed in the back-end etc.

Comment: Well... Upon writing first 2-letters in searchBar it should show autosuggestions based on mysql table 'herbs' in 'herbarium' databse...  It was done basing on https://www.arielmax.com/38-cursos-de-jquery-jquery-ui/ but his works.
Console doesn't show any errors... I know there's no protection yet, will be added

Comment: Add breaking points and see where exactly your code breaks.

Comment: @farmaceut: "It doesn't work" isn't really useful debugging info.  This is your opportunity to start to familiarize yourself with the concept of debugging.  Use your browser's debugging tools.  Step through the code as it executes, observe the HTTP requests and responses, observe the runtime values of your variables, etc.  Additionally, PHP errors won't show on the console.  Check your PHP logs for errors, turn on error reporting, etc.  Again, you are also wide open to SQL injection and not checking for database errors.  It could be failing very loudly and you're not listening to it.

Comment: @David
I changed, by adding alert:
`success: function(data){ response(data); alert('Success');}, error: function(jqxhr,status,exception) {alert('ERROR',exception);}`
And all I get is "error"... 
Theres some problems with connection maybe, because even first line in php: `echo ("Error");` doesnt appear :S

Comment: @Haem I added  some stuff to check errors (described in response to David)

Comment: @pr1ince  Added and as I see it breaks in .js script. It probably doesnt reach php script, because there's no echo that's before connecting with database

Answer (score 0):

Fixed... The problem was using 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1' on my Mac. Came on it accidently, while trying to create new .php file and access it by webbrowser.